Google Maps and Google ReCaptcha, how to be GDPR Cookies Compliant with Angular 18?
I want to build a site using Angular 18, in this site I'm using Google Maps widget, and I want to use Google ReCaptcha.
Now I want to be compliant with EU Cookie Law, what do you recommend for achieving it?
Thank you so much
I tried to search on WEB, and to search for apposite libraries, but I didn't get how to do

You can use ngx-cookieconsent.
load it in your app config or module:


import {NgcCookieConsentConfig} from 'ngx-cookieconsent';
import {provideNgcCookieConsent} from 'ngx-cookieconsent';

const cookieConfig:NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  cookie: {
    domain: 'localhost'
  },
  palette: {
    popup: {
      background: '#000'
    },
    button: {
      background: '#f1d600'
    }
  },
  theme: 'edgeless',
  type: 'opt-out'
};

// App.config
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideNgcCookieConsent(cookieConfig),
  ]
});

//////// App.module

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConfig), ...],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}



you can use it like this


constructor(private readonly ccService: NgcCookieConsentService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe((event: { status: string }) => {
    if (event.status === 'allow') {
      this.loadGoogleMaps();
      this.loadReCaptcha();
    }
  });
}

loadGoogleMaps() {
  // load map
}

loadReCaptcha() {
  // load recaptcha service';
}




Hi, thank you so much for your reply, I'll try in this way.
A question: can I load required JS for these widget anyway, or after user accepted cookies?
